# Number of Rows is Different Between UPDATE and SELECT Statement in MS Access SQL

Tags: sql, ms-access, join, sql-update, left-join

I have exactly the same problem as in this thread [Different number of rows affected when using select or update with the same parameters - PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7316514/different-number-of-rows-affected-when-using-select-or-update-with-the-same-para) but I am using MS Access so the solution does not work for me. (Or I am doing it wrong)

These 2 statements return a different number of rows:

```
SELECT c.hole_id, c.level, c.section, c.valid, c.holetype, a.hole_id
FROM collar AS c LEFT JOIN assay AS a
ON a.hole_id = c.hole_id
WHERE c.holetype="Channel" AND a.hole_id Is Null;
```

And

```
UPDATE collar AS c 
SET c.valid = no
WHERE EXISTS
     (SELECT c.hole_id, c.level, c.section, c.valid, c.holetype, a.hole_id   
     FROM collar AS c LEFT JOIN assay AS a
     ON a.hole_id = c.hole_id
     WHERE c.holetype="Channel" AND a.hole_id Is Null);
```

The basic logic is that any record in *collar* that does not have a related record in *assay* (*hole_id* is the primary key/foreign key) must be *no* in the field *valid*.

So I saw the answer saying that UPDATE is self-joining, so I get what the solution is but I can't make this work in Access - I get no rows returned.

```
UPDATE collar AS c, assay AS a
SET c.valid = no
WHERE a.hole_id = c.hole_id AND c.holetype="Channel" AND a.hole_id Is Null;
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Why are you using same alias `c` for inner and outer queries? At first glance I'd assume your update will update every row due to this.

Comment: Does it matter? I just copied and pasted it and they refer to the same tables. It works exactly the same if I take it out.

Comment: I worked with Access for a very long time and I have never set any column to the unquoted `yes/no` value which appears to be same as `true/false`. Very interesting!

Comment: Please put everything & only what is needed to ask your question in your post, not just at a link. Quote with credit & relate to your question. Debug questions require a [mre]. [ask] [Help]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to update:

> any record in collar that does **not** have a related record in assay

which means that you should use `NOT EXISTS`:

```
UPDATE collar AS c 
SET c.valid = no
WHERE c.holetype = 'Channel' 
  AND NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT *
        FROM assay AS a
        WHERE a.hole_id = c.hole_id
      );
```

If you want to use a join in the `UPDATE` statement then the correct syntax for Access is:

```
UPDATE collar AS c  
LEFT JOIN assay AS a ON a.hole_id = c.hole_id
SET c.valid = no
WHERE c.holetype='Channel' AND a.hole_id IS NULL;
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this :

```
Update collar c 
LEFT JOIN assay AS a ON a.hole_id = c.hole_id
set c.valid = 'no'
WHERE c.holetype='Channel' AND a.hole_id Is Null;
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/9dJnTEfk)

Comment: Tried it. It does not like the FROM after SET c.valid = no

Comment: Access uses `UPDATE..JOIN` syntax similar to MySQL not `UPDATE...FROM` like SQL Server or Postgres.

Comment: Thank you! I have removed FROM and didn't realise to move the SET clause to after the JOIN.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the `IN` operator with different alias to `collar` in subquery:

```sql
UPDATE collar AS c 
SET c.valid = no 
WHERE c.hole_id IN (
    SELECT sub_c.hole_id
    FROM collar AS sub_c 
    LEFT JOIN assay AS a 
      ON a.hole_id = sub_c.hole_id
    WHERE sub_c.holetype = 'Channel' 
      AND a.hole_id IS NULL
);
```

Alternatively, keep with `EXISTS` but add a condition for outer table and inner subquery correlation without reusing aliases.

```sql
UPDATE collar AS c 
SET c.valid = no 
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM collar AS sub_c 
    LEFT JOIN assay AS a 
      ON a.hole_id = sub_c.hole_id
    WHERE sub_c.holetype = 'Channel' 
      AND a.hole_id IS NULL
      AND c.hole_id = sub_c.hole_id
);
```

But it is more concise to use `NOT EXISTS` as @forpas [shows](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75847611/1422451) without referring to `collar` tables twice.